# Get all directories within directory nodejs

Tags: node.js, directory

I was hoping this would be a simple thing, but I cannot find anything out there to do so.

I just want to get all folders/directories within a given folder/directory.

So for example:

```
<MyFolder>
|- SomeFolder
|- SomeOtherFolder
|- SomeFile.txt
|- SomeOtherFile.txt
|- x-directory
```

I would expect to get an array of:

```
["SomeFolder", "SomeOtherFolder", "x-directory"]
```

Or the above with the path if that was how it was served...

So does anything already exist to do the above?

Answer (score 744, accepted):

**Promise**

```
import { readdir } from 'fs/promises'

const getDirectories = async source =>
  (await readdir(source, { withFileTypes: true }))
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map(dirent => dirent.name)
```

**Callback**

```
import { readdir } from 'fs'

const getDirectories = (source, callback) =>
  readdir(source, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err)
    } else {
      callback(
        files
          .filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())
          .map(dirent => dirent.name)
      )
    }
  })
```

**Syncronous**

```
import { readdirSync } from 'fs'

const getDirectories = source =>
  readdirSync(source, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map(dirent => dirent.name)
```

Comment: Careful, you need the absolut path to get the file stat. ``require('path').resolve(__dirname, file)``

Comment: @pilau it just doesn't work with a relative path, thats why you need to normalize it. For that you can use path.resolve.

Comment: @rickysullivan: You'd need to iterate through the response and use path.resolve(srcpath, foldername) for each folder inside

Comment: Since you're using es6: `const getDirectories = srcPath => fs.readdirSync(srcPath).filter(file => fs.statSync(path.join(srcPath, file)).isDirectory())`

Comment: Note this breaks if there are symlinks in the directory. Use `lstatSync` instead.

Comment: const getDirectories = async source =>
  (await readdirSync(source, { withFileTypes: true }))
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map(dirent => dirent.name);

Comment: There’s no need to `await` a synchronous function. If you want to do this asynchronously with Promises, follow that example instead.

Answer (score 84):

List directories using a path.

```
function getDirectories(path) {
  return fs.readdirSync(path).filter(function (file) {
    return fs.statSync(path+'/'+file).isDirectory();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 49):

#### Recursive solution

I came here in search of a way to get all of the subdirectories, and all of their subdirectories, etc. Building on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24594123/437), I wrote this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function flatten(lists) {
  return lists.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
}

function getDirectories(srcpath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath)
    .map(file => path.join(srcpath, file))
    .filter(path => fs.statSync(path).isDirectory());
}

function getDirectoriesRecursive(srcpath) {
  return [srcpath, ...flatten(getDirectories(srcpath).map(getDirectoriesRecursive))];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it seems to work great except that every path except the first one appears like this : "src\\pages\\partials\\buttons" instead of this "src/pages/partials/buttons". I added this dirty fix: 
var res = getDirectoriesRecursive(srcpath);
res = res.map(function(x){ return x.replace(/\\/g,"/") });
console.log(res);

Comment: A less dirty way to do that is path.normalize(). https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path

Comment: You are returning the parent directory, which is not desirable. I would refactor getDirectoriesRecursive to prevent that: 
`if (recursive) return [srcpath, ...flatten(getDirectories(srcpath).map(getDirectoriesRecursive))];
else return [...flatten(getDirectories(srcpath).map(getDirectoriesRecursive))];
}`

Answer (score 13):

This should do it:

**CoffeeScript (sync)**

```
fs = require 'fs'

getDirs = (rootDir) ->
    files = fs.readdirSync(rootDir)
    dirs = []

    for file in files
        if file[0] != '.'
            filePath = "#{rootDir}/#{file}"
            stat = fs.statSync(filePath)

            if stat.isDirectory()
                dirs.push(file)

    return dirs
```

**CoffeeScript (async)**

```
fs = require 'fs'

getDirs = (rootDir, cb) ->
    fs.readdir rootDir, (err, files) ->
        dirs = []

        for file, index in files
            if file[0] != '.'
                filePath = "#{rootDir}/#{file}"
                fs.stat filePath, (err, stat) ->
                    if stat.isDirectory()
                        dirs.push(file)
                    if files.length == (index + 1)
                        cb(dirs)
```

**JavaScript (async)**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var getDirs = function(rootDir, cb) { 
    fs.readdir(rootDir, function(err, files) { 
        var dirs = []; 
        for (var index = 0; index < files.length; ++index) { 
            var file = files[index]; 
            if (file[0] !== '.') { 
                var filePath = rootDir + '/' + file; 
                fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stat) {
                    if (stat.isDirectory()) { 
                        dirs.push(this.file); 
                    } 
                    if (files.length === (this.index + 1)) { 
                        return cb(dirs); 
                    } 
                }.bind({index: index, file: file})); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Although if this is for a production system, you really want to avoid the synchronous `fs` methods.

Comment: oh there is an "isDirectory" method, ace! thanks for your help! (it is for a build script)

Comment: Note to any newbies reading this answer: this is CoffeeScript, not JavaScript (my friend messaged me in confusion asking why JavaScript suddenly had semantic whitespace).

Comment: @nicksweet Can you convert this to JS?

Comment: @mikemaccana
var fs = require('fs');

var getDirs = function(rootDir, cb)
{
 fs.readdir(rootDir, function(err, files)
 {
  var dirs = [];

  for (index = 0, index < files.length; ++index)
  {
   file = files[index];

   if (file[0] !== '.')
   {
    filePath = rootDir + '/' + file;
    fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stat)
    {
     if (stat.isDirectory())
     {
      dirs.push(file);
     }
     if (files.length === (index + 1))
     {
      return cb(dirs);
     }
    });
   }
  }
 });
};

Comment: Thanks @alex but was asking OP to fix their answer per StackOverflow rules.

Comment: That javascript conversion is bad. You are accessing mutable properties from inside a closure (index and file). That should be fixed.

Comment: There are some glaring problems with this answer: it does not have any error handling; (the callback signature should be `(err, dirs)`); it won't call back in the presence of dot files or folders; it is susceptible to all the race conditions; it may call back before it has checked all the entries.

Comment: Ug, people need to stop vilifying the sync api. Determining whether or not a sync version should be used is not determined by it being "production". Also repeating ad nauseum that the async api's are better and sync is bad, without context, is just not accurate. I wish the JS community would stop promulgating this. Sync is simpler (yay) but will block the message loop (boo). So, don't use sync api's in a server where you don't want to block but feel free to use them in a build script for example where that doesn't matter. </rant>

Comment: unfortunately async version doesn't work for me. If I try to console.log file, it prints last file in every iteration.

Comment: You should note that you're using CoffeeScript up front to make this answer more accessible to developers of all levels.  The original post is not asking for CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 8):

With node.js version >= v10.13.0, [fs.readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) will return an array of [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects if `withFileTypes` option is set to `true`.

So you can use,

```
const fs = require('fs')

const directories = source => fs.readdirSync(source, {
   withFileTypes: true
}).reduce((a, c) => {
   c.isDirectory() && a.push(c.name)
   return a
}, [])
```

Comment: good point, but `.filter(c => c.isDirectory())` would be simpler than using `reduce()`

Comment: Yes, but filter returns an array of fs.Dirent objects which are directories. The OP wanted names of directories.

Comment: true, I would still prefer `.filter(c => c.isDirectory()).map(c => c.name)` over the `reduce` call though.

Comment: i see your point. i guess SO readers can decide based on their use-case. i'd say that looping over an in-memory array should be negligible in overhead compared to the I/O of reading from disk, even if you're reading from SSD, but as usual if one really cares, they can measure.

Answer (score 8):

```
 var getDirectories = (rootdir , cb) => {
    fs.readdir(rootdir, (err, files) => {
        if(err) throw err ;
        var dirs = files.map(filename => path.join(rootdir,filename)).filter( pathname => fs.statSync(pathname).isDirectory());
        return cb(dirs);
    })

 }
 getDirectories( myDirectories => console.log(myDirectories));``
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, if you are able to use external libraries, you can use `filehound`. It supports callbacks, promises and sync calls.

**Using promises:**

```
const Filehound = require('filehound');

Filehound.create()
  .path("MyFolder")
  .directory() // only search for directories
  .find()
  .then((subdirectories) => {
    console.log(subdirectories);
  });
```

**Using callbacks:**

```
const Filehound = require('filehound');

Filehound.create()
  .path("MyFolder")
  .directory()
  .find((err, subdirectories) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    console.log(subdirectories);
  });
```

**Sync call:**

```
const Filehound = require('filehound');

const subdirectories = Filehound.create()
  .path("MyFolder")
  .directory()
  .findSync();

console.log(subdirectories);
```

For further information (and examples), check out the docs: https://github.com/nspragg/filehound

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 5):

Using fs-extra, which promises the async fs calls, and the new await async syntax:

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function getDirectories(path){
    let filesAndDirectories = await fs.readdir(path);

    let directories = [];
    await Promise.all(
        filesAndDirectories.map(name =>{
            return fs.stat(path + name)
            .then(stat =>{
                if(stat.isDirectory()) directories.push(name)
            })
        })
    );
    return directories;
}

let directories = await getDirectories("/")
```

Comment: Not working on my end. It throws an error when it encounters the `.git` file.

Answer (score 4):

This answer does not use blocking functions like `readdirSync` or `statSync`. It does not use external dependencies nor find itself in the depths of callback hell.

Instead we use modern JavaScript conveniences like Promises and and `async-await` syntaxes. And asynchronous results are processed in parallel; not sequentially -

```
const { readdir, stat } =
  require ("fs") .promises

const { join } =
  require ("path")

const dirs = async (path = ".") =>
  (await stat (path)) .isDirectory ()
    ? Promise
        .all
          ( (await readdir (path))
              .map (p => dirs (join (path, p)))
          )
        .then
          ( results =>
              [] .concat (path, ...results)
          )
    : []
```

I'll install an example package, and then test our function -

```
$ npm install ramda
$ node
```

Let's see it work -

```
> dirs (".") .then (console.log, console.error)

[ '.'
, 'node_modules'
, 'node_modules/ramda'
, 'node_modules/ramda/dist'
, 'node_modules/ramda/es'
, 'node_modules/ramda/es/internal'
, 'node_modules/ramda/src'
, 'node_modules/ramda/src/internal'
]
```

---

Using a generalised module, `Parallel`, we can simplify the definition of `dirs` -

```
const Parallel =
  require ("./Parallel")

const dirs = async (path = ".") =>
  (await stat (path)) .isDirectory ()
    ? Parallel (readdir (path))
        .flatMap (f => dirs (join (path, f)))
        .then (results => [ path, ...results ])
    : []
```

The `Parallel` module used above was a pattern that was extracted from a set of functions designed to solve a similar problem. For more explanation, see this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225285/633183).

Answer (score 3):

And a async version of getDirectories, you need the [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) for this:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async'); // https://github.com/caolan/async

// Original function
function getDirsSync(srcpath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory();
  });
}

function getDirs(srcpath, cb) {
  fs.readdir(srcpath, function (err, files) {
    if(err) { 
      console.error(err);
      return cb([]);
    }
    var iterator = function (file, cb)  {
      fs.stat(path.join(srcpath, file), function (err, stats) {
        if(err) { 
          console.error(err);
          return cb(false);
        }
        cb(stats.isDirectory());
      })
    }
    async.filter(files, iterator, cb);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fully async version with ES6, only native packages, fs.promises and async/await, does file operations in parallel:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function listDirectories(rootPath) {
    const fileNames = await fs.promises.readdir(rootPath);
    const filePaths = fileNames.map(fileName => path.join(rootPath, fileName));
    const filePathsAndIsDirectoryFlagsPromises = filePaths.map(async filePath => ({path: filePath, isDirectory: (await fs.promises.stat(filePath)).isDirectory()}))
    const filePathsAndIsDirectoryFlags = await Promise.all(filePathsAndIsDirectoryFlagsPromises);
    return filePathsAndIsDirectoryFlags.filter(filePathAndIsDirectoryFlag => filePathAndIsDirectoryFlag.isDirectory)
        .map(filePathAndIsDirectoryFlag => filePathAndIsDirectoryFlag.path);
}
```

Tested, it works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can use [graph-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graph-fs)

```js
const {Node} = require("graph-fs");
const directory = new Node("/path/to/directory");

const subDirectories = directory.children.filter(child => child.is.directory);
```

Answer (score 1):

CoffeeScript version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28299467/2624876), with proper error handling:

```
fs = require "fs"
{join} = require "path"
async = require "async"

get_subdirs = (root, callback)->
    fs.readdir root, (err, files)->
        return callback err if err
        subdirs = []
        async.each files,
            (file, callback)->
                fs.stat join(root, file), (err, stats)->
                    return callback err if err
                    subdirs.push file if stats.isDirectory()
                    callback null
            (err)->
                return callback err if err
                callback null, subdirs
```

Depends on [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Alternatively, [use a module for this!](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subdirs)
(There are modules for everything. [citation needed])

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use all `async` version. You can have something like this.

1. Record the directory length, uses it as an indicator to tell if all async stat tasks are finished.
2. If the async stat tasks are finished, all the file stat has been checked, so call the callback

This will only work as long as Node.js is single thread, because it assumes no two async tasks will increase the counter at the same time.

```
'use strict';

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var basePath = "./";

function result_callback(results) {
    results.forEach((obj) => {
        console.log("isFile: " + obj.fileName);
        console.log("fileName: " + obj.isFile);
    });
};

fs.readdir(basePath, (err, files) => {
    var results = [];
    var total = files.length;
    var finished = 0;

    files.forEach((fileName) => {
        // console.log(fileName);
        var fullPath = path.join(basePath, fileName);

        fs.stat(fullPath, (err, stat) => {
            // this will work because Node.js is single thread
            // therefore, the counter will not increment at the same time by two callback
            finished++;

            if (stat.isFile()) {
                results.push({
                    fileName: fileName,
                    isFile: stat.isFile()
                });
            }

            if (finished == total) {
                result_callback(results);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, this is a "depth first" approach, and this could result in callback hell, and it is not quite "functional" . People try to solve this problem with Promise, by wrapping the async task into an Promise object.

```
'use strict';

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var basePath = "./";

function result_callback(results) {
    results.forEach((obj) => {
        console.log("isFile: " + obj.fileName);
        console.log("fileName: " + obj.isFile);
    });
};

fs.readdir(basePath, (err, files) => {
    var results = [];
    var total = files.length;
    var finished = 0;

    var promises = files.map((fileName) => {
        // console.log(fileName);
        var fullPath = path.join(basePath, fileName);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // try to replace fullPath wil "aaa", it will reject
            fs.stat(fullPath, (err, stat) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }

                var obj = {
                    fileName: fileName,
                    isFile: stat.isFile()
                };

                resolve(obj);
            });
        });
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
        console.log("All the promise resolved");
        console.log(values);
        console.log("Filter out folder: ");
        values
            .filter((obj) => obj.isFile)
            .forEach((obj) => {
                console.log(obj.fileName);
            });
    }, (reason) => {
        console.log("Not all the promise resolved");
        console.log(reason);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good code! But I think it should be "Filter out files: " in Promise.all block as it is checking if it is a file and logging it. :)

Answer (score 1):

use **fs、path** module can got the folder. this use Promise. If your will get the fill, your can change **isDirectory()** to **isFile()** [Nodejs--fs--fs.Stats](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_fstatsync_fd).At last, you can get the file'name file'extname and so on [Nodejs---Path](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_extname_path)

```
var fs = require("fs"),
path = require("path");
//your <MyFolder> path
var p = "MyFolder"
fs.readdir(p, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    //this can get all folder and file under  <MyFolder>
    files.map(function (file) {
        //return file or folder path, such as **MyFolder/SomeFile.txt**
        return path.join(p, file);
    }).filter(function (file) {
        //use sync judge method. The file will add next files array if the file is directory, or not. 
        return fs.statSync(file).isDirectory();
    }).forEach(function (files) {
        //The files is array, so each. files is the folder name. can handle the folder.
        console.log("%s", files);
    });
});
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package, just add a trailing slash to find directories only:

```
import {promise as glob} from "glob-promise"

const firstLevelFolders = await glob("MyFolder/*/")
const recursiveFolders = await glob("MyFolder/**/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else ends up here from a web search, and has Grunt already in their dependency list, the answer to this becomes trivial. Here's my solution:

```
/**
 * Return all the subfolders of this path
 * @param {String} parentFolderPath - valid folder path
 * @param {String} glob ['/*'] - optional glob so you can do recursive if you want
 * @returns {String[]} subfolder paths
 */
getSubfolders = (parentFolderPath, glob = '/*') => {
    return grunt.file.expand({filter: 'isDirectory'}, parentFolderPath + glob);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another recursive approach

Thanks to Mayur for knowing me about `withFileTypes`. I written following code for getting files of particular folder recursively. It can be easily modified to get only directories.

```
const getFiles = (dir, base = '') => readdirSync(dir, {withFileTypes: true}).reduce((files, file) => {
    const filePath = path.join(dir, file.name)
    const relativePath = path.join(base, file.name)
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        return files.concat(getFiles(filePath, relativePath))
    } else if(file.isFile()) {
        file.__fullPath = filePath
        file.__relateivePath = relativePath
        return files.concat(file)
    }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

functional programming

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const R = require('ramda')

const getDirectories = pathName => {
    const isDirectory = pathName => fs.lstatSync(pathName).isDirectory()
    const mapDirectories = pathName => R.map(name => path.join(pathName, name), fs.readdirSync(pathName))
    const filterDirectories = listPaths => R.filter(isDirectory, listPaths)

    return {
        paths:R.pipe(mapDirectories)(pathName),
        pathsFiltered: R.pipe(mapDirectories, filterDirectories)(pathName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dree), if using a module is affordable

```js
const dree = require('dree');

const options = {
  depth: 1
};
const fileCallback = function() {};

const directories = [];
const dirCallback = function(dir) {
 directories.push(dir.name);
};

dree.scan('./dir', {});

console.log(directories);
```

The directories which are directed children of the specified path ("./dir") will be printed.

If you do not put the option `depth: 1`, you would even obtain all the directories in a recursively way, so not only the directed children of the specified path.