# require all folders as modules inside folder?

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a lot of folders as modules that contains my rest api, the structure is the following:

```
app
|— server
|  |— rest-api
|  |  |— v1
|  |  |  |— module-one
|  |  |  |— module-two
|  |  |  |— module-three
|  |  |  |— module-x
|  |  |  └── index.js
|  |  └──...
|  └──...
|— ...
└── server.js
```

What I want to avoid at `v1/index.js` is the following:

```
module.exports = (function () {

    var express      = require( 'express' ),
        router       = express.Router(),
        module_one   = require( './module-one' ),
        module_two   = require( './module-two' ),
        module_three = require( './module-three' );
    //...

    router.use( module_one );
    router.use( module_two );
    router.use( module_three );
    //...

    return router;

})();
```

Is there a way to read all them at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112204/get-all-directories-within-directory-nodejs) SO post

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

function loadAllModules(srcpath, router) {
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function(file) {
    if(fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory()) {
      var module = require('./' + file);
      router.use(module)
    }
  });
}
```

And then use it like:

`loadAllModules(__dirname, router)`

```
module.exports = (function () {

    var express      = require( 'express' ),
        router       = express.Router();
    //...

    loadAllModules(__dirname, router);
    return router;

})();
```

Comment: Can I declare `loadAllModules` at `server.js` and use it at `/server/rest-api/v1/index.js`?

Comment: You could declare it under `GLOBAL` inside `server.js` to have it accessible everywhere. `GLOBAL.loadAllModules = function(directory, router) {...}`

Comment: What do you mean by `__dirname`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js

Comment: I mean the current directory

Comment: It worked, but what would be the difference between sync vs async in this case?

Comment: Yes, sync guarantees you that all the `require` will be done when the function ends and the control is handed over to `server.js` again and eventually hit the `server.listen` line

Answer (score 2):

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-all
```

Check this module, if it fulfills your node.

We have used this module for requiring all Mongoose Schema And Controllers.

Update:

```
var controllers = require('require-all')({
    dirname     :  __dirname + '/server/rest-api/',
    filter      :  'index.js',
    recursive   : true
});
```

Comment: Would you like to make an example according to the situation?, require only folders, or index.js under each folder of a folder...

Comment: I have Updated example for your situation.

Comment: But what about the index.js from where that is called, will it be recalled?

Comment: Assign dirname property from which you want to require, from that it will check all folders recursively and require it's index.js