# how to print all sub directory - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, subdirectory

again im stack with node.js and need your help.

i try to write script for cmd that search for all sub directory under current dir(process.cwd),
and print just the one's that contain a string the user has given me (with process.argv[2]).

i was looking here for some answar without succsess.
also try do it with 'stat.isDirectory' and 'fs.readdir', but im still need to learn way more to do it.

hope that someone can help me,

thanks anyway,
eyal

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112204/get-all-directories-within-directory-nodejs#24594123

Comment: ok, thanks. but how i print just the one's  that contain the string the user given me?

Comment: Why don't you loop through the directory names and filter that..like `var userStr = 'user_provided_string'; getDirectories('.').forEach(function(dirName,i){
 if(dirName.indexOf(userStr) > -1){
  console.log(dirName); return;
 }
});`

Comment: like that? https://jsfiddle.net/eyal4/etfc8unp/ , still dont print anything. maybe if i put all the sub dirs in array and then do a loop ?

Comment: not like this, `getDirectories` is synchronous, you can call it outside that function.. move the code to the outside the `getDirectories` function. check https://jsfiddle.net/5ycm5uxd/1/ but i am not sure about the output.

Comment: maybe its the right answar but still dont print anything. there is another way? ive been try also to print it with che stdout.

Comment: why are you trying this server code in client side, try this in node server

Comment: this is a mission ive had to do for a class. what do you mean by in node server? its supposed to be on cmd.

Comment: i mean this is a server side script, should run on server. this will not work on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `getDirectories` function from this link [Get all directories within directory nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112204/get-all-directories-within-directory-nodejs#24594123)

try this code in server side

```
var fs = require('fs'),path = require('path');
var userStr = 'user_provided_string'; 

function getDirectories(srcpath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory();
  });
}

getDirectories('.').forEach(function(dirName,i){
    if(dirName.indexOf(userStr) > -1){ 
       console.log(dirName); 
       return; 
    } 
});
```