# NodeJS fs.statSync(...).isDirectory() returns true for file

Tags: node.js, path, fs

Attempting to use the code from the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24594123/3951987

Returns true for a file inside a directory for me.

To provide more context, here's some basic code to describe my implementation:

```
getDirs = (a_path) => {
    return fs.readdirSync(a_path)
        .filter(file => fs.statSync(path.join(a_path, file)).isDirectory());
}

someCode = () => {
    let some_path = path.resolve(process.cwd(), "example");
    console.log(getDirs(some_path));
}
```

In my project, I have:

```
example/
- test/
- manifest.json
index.js
```

Somehow the getDirs function described above still returns manifest.json as a directory, even with the given filter applied.

Anyone else had this? Any ideas?

**Additional Information**

I've modified the getDirs function to the following:

```
getDirs = (a_path) => {
    console.log("getDirs a_path = "+a_path);
    let dirs = fs.readdirSync(a_path);

    for(let x = 0; x<dirs.length; x++){
        let a_dir = path.resolve(a_path, dirs[x]);
        console.log(dirs[x]);
        console.log(fs.statSync(a_path, a_dir).isDirectory());
    }
    return dirs;
};
```

The output for this is:

```
getDirs a_path = <pathtoproject>/example
test
true
manifest.json
true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
console.log(fs.statSync(a_path, a_dir).isDirectory());
```

to:

```
console.log(fs.statSync(a_dir).isDirectory());
```

Otherwise your stating the `a_path`, not `a_dir`.

`fs.statSync` takes one argument - see the docs:

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path

Comment: Ugh, such a small oversight giving me a headache... Well spotted sir :)

Comment: Looking back, since I dont need to compile my absolute paths, the example i used had fs.statSync(path.join(... where, I pass the path directly

Comment: @N15M0_jk Yes, and your first example works well with: `.filter(file => fs.statSync(path.join(a_path, file)).isDirectory());`