# How to require files and files in sub-folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node-modules

I have these files in folder X: 1.js 2.js, 3.js
and this is my code

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./X');

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const files= require(`./X/${file}`);
}
```

This currently gets the files 1,2,3 and stores it under `files`

I want to add a subfolder within folder X with more .js files here's an example:

- X=>contains 1.js, 2.js,3.js and folder Y in it
- Y=>contains a.js,b.js

So how would I add these new js files in folder Y to the `const` `files`?

Comment: This looks to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40896897/127606

Comment: @Jarede That answer is to get the directories, I want to get the js files

Comment: You can extrapolate from that answer and your current code to get what you want.

Comment: @Jarede I don't know how to...

Comment: We're not going to write the code for you.  that isn't the point of SO.  you've got this far, you've been given the next piece of the puzzle, you can try to put them together, then come back and create a new question for where it's going wrong.

Comment: @Jarede Like I said i don't know how! i'm just going to but a.js,b.js in folder X :/