# Await an iterative function without delimiter in JS

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

I've got a directory with an unknown amount of subfolders. Each subfolder might have or not further subfolders. I am itterating through them using a recursive function. Due to the unknown amounts of subfolders I am missing a way to make sure that all folders have been checked before I continue. My knowledge on async and await is quiet limited. Is there any Way to handle this problem?

```
function searchForPackage(directory){
    fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files){
        if(err){
            return;
        }else{
            files.forEach(file => {
                var currentLocation = directory + "/" + file;
                if(fs.statSync(currentLocation).isDirectory() && file != 'bin' && file != '.bin'){
                    searchForPackage(currentLocation);
                    return;
                }else if(file == "package.json"){
                    var content = fs.readFileSync(currentLocation);
                    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
                    var obj = {
                        name: jsonContent.name,
                        license: jsonContent.license,
                        version: jsonContent.version
                    }
                    jsonTable.push(obj);
                    jsonTable.push({name: jsonContent.name, license: jsonContent.license, version: jsonContent.version});
                    return;
                }
            })
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Where is `async` and `await`? Where are the Promises?

Comment: There is no async and await yet nor is there a promise...Thats why I'm asking...i have no clue how to apply asynchronity here

Comment: @JannikMottulla [Find a way to get a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) for `fs.readdir(…)`, then [use `await` in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572). Please try something.

Comment: @Bergi The filestream is sync. My problem is that i dunno how to figure out when my function ran through all subfolders.

Comment: `readFileSync` is sync, `readdir` is not. Make a promise and await it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) Since everything else is done using `fs`'s synchronous methods, you could change `fs.readdir` to `fs.readdirSync`:

```
function searchForPackage(directory) {
  fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach(file => {
    var currentLocation = directory + "/" + file;
    if (fs.statSync(currentLocation).isDirectory() && file != 'bin' && file != '.bin') {
      searchForPackage(currentLocation);
      return;
    } else if (file == "package.json") {
      var content = fs.readFileSync(currentLocation);
      var jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
      var obj = {
        name: jsonContent.name,
        license: jsonContent.license,
        version: jsonContent.version
      }
      jsonTable.push(obj);
      jsonTable.push({name: jsonContent.name, license: jsonContent.license, version: jsonContent.version});
      return;
    }
  })
}
```

2) Convert `fs.readdirSync` to a `Promise` and then use `async/await`:

```
async function searchForPackage(directory) {
  const files = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(files);
    });
  });
  await Promise.all(files.map(async file => {
    var currentLocation = directory + "/" + file;
    if (fs.statSync(currentLocation).isDirectory() && file != 'bin' && file != '.bin') {
      await searchForPackage(currentLocation);
      return;
    } else if (file == "package.json") {
      var content = fs.readFileSync(currentLocation);
      var jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
      var obj = {
        name: jsonContent.name,
        license: jsonContent.license,
        version: jsonContent.version
      }
      jsonTable.push(obj);
      jsonTable.push({name: jsonContent.name, license: jsonContent.license, version: jsonContent.version});
      return;
    }
  }))
}
```

3) Use a couple third-party modules to clean things up a bit ([`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) takes care of promisifying asynchronous methods like `fs.readdir` for you. [`async-af`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-af) provides chainable asynchronous JavaScript methods such as a parallel [`forEach`](https://async-af.js.org/AsyncAF#forEachAF).):

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const AsyncAF = require('async-af');

async function searchForPackage(directory) {
  await AsyncAF(fs.readdir(directory)).forEach(async file => {
    var currentLocation = directory + "/" + file;
    if (fs.statSync(currentLocation).isDirectory() && file != 'bin' && file != '.bin') {
      await searchForPackage(currentLocation);
    } else if (file == "package.json") {
      var content = fs.readFileSync(currentLocation);
      var jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
      var obj = {
        name: jsonContent.name,
        license: jsonContent.license,
        version: jsonContent.version
      }
      jsonTable.push(obj);
      jsonTable.push({name: jsonContent.name, license: jsonContent.license, version: jsonContent.version});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I guess i failed at explaining my Problem...My code is running fine so far. I am writing the extracted obj's into an array. If all folders have been checked I'd like to parse the array of obj's in .json. I need a way to wait for all folders to be checked (not loaded), otherwise i would get an empty array.

Comment: I tested on one of my projects with multiple `package.json`s and it worked; the trick is (if you're using `fs.readdir` and not `fs.readdirSync`) you have to `await` running the function so the array has time to populate. For example: `(async () => {
  await searchForPackage('./');
  console.log(jsonTable);
})()`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building smaller functions with isolated concerns. Start with a `files` function that simply returns all files and the files of all sub-directories -

```
const { readdir, stat } =
  require ("fs") .promises

const { join } =
  require ("path")

const files = async (path = ".") =>
  (await stat (path)) .isDirectory ()
    ? Promise
        .all
          ( (await readdir (path))
              .map (f => files (join (path, f)))
          )
        .then
          ( results =>
             [] .concat (...results)
          )
    : [ path ]

files () .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ './.main.js'
// , './node_modules/anotherpackage/README.md'
// , './node_modules/anotherpackage/package.json'
// , './node_modules/anotherpackage/index.js'
// , './node_modules/somepackage/.npmignore'
// , './node_modules/somepackage/LICENSE'
// , './node_modules/somepackage/README.md'
// , './node_modules/somepackage/package.json'
// , './node_modules/somepackage/index.js'
// , './node_modules/somepackage/test/test.js'
// , './package.json'
// ]
```

Then make a `search` function which depends on `files` and adds the capability to filter results -

```
const { basename } =
  require ("path")

const search = async (query, path = ".") =>
  (await files (path))
    .filter (x => basename (x) === query)

search ("package.json", ".")
  .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ './node_modules/anotherpackage/package.json'
// , './node_modules/somepackage/package.json'
// , './package.json'
// ]
```

Then make your `readPackages` function which depends on `search` and adds the capability to read/parse the packages -

```
const { readFile } =
  require ("fs") .promises

const readPackages = async (path = ".") =>
  Promise
    .all
      ( (await search ("package.json", path))
          .map (package => readFile (package))
      )
    .then
      ( buffers =>
          buffers .map (b => JSON .parse (String (b)))
      )

readPackages ('.')
  .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ <contents of anotherpackage/package.json>
// , <contents of somepackage/package.json>
// , <contents of package.json>
// ]
```

Finally, notice how `jsonTable` is no longer a global. Instead all data is nicely contained and flowing through our sequence of promises.

---

If you'd like the transform the packages as you're reading them, you can make `transform` a parameter of the `readPackages` function. This keeps it generic and allows you to read package contents in a user-specified way -

```
const readPackages = async (transform, path = ".") =>
  Promise
    .all
      ( (await search ("package.json", path))
          .map (package => readFile (package))
      )
    .then
      ( buffers =>
          buffers .map (b => transform (JSON .parse (String (b))))
      )

readPackages
  ( ({ name }) => ({ name }) 
  , '.'
  )
  .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ { name: 'anotherpackage' }
// , { name: 'somepackage' }
// , { name: 'mypackage' }
// ]
```

Or get `name`, `version`, and `license` -

```
readPackages
  ( ({ name, version, license = "None" }) =>
      ({ name, version, license }) 
  , '.'
  )
  .then (console.log, console.error)

// [ { name: 'anotherpackage', version: '1.0.0', license: 'None' }
// , { name: 'somepackage', version: '3.2.1', license: 'MIT' }
// , { name: 'mypackage', version: '1.2.3', license: 'BSD-3-Clause' }
// ]
```

---

Now in these simplified programs, we start to see some patterns emerging. To make our intentions more clear and avoid repeating ourselves, we design a reusable module -

```
const Parallel = p =>
  ( { map: async f =>
        Promise .all ((await p) .map (x => f (x)))
    , filter: async f =>
        (await p) .filter (x => f (x))
    , flatMap: async f =>
        Promise .all ((await p) .map (x => f (x))) .then (ys => [] .concat (...ys))
    , // ...
    }
  )
```

Now our `files` function is a lot nicer -

```
const files = async (path = ".") =>
  (await stat (path)) .isDirectory ()
    ? Parallel (readdir (path))
        .flatMap (f => files (join (path, f)))
    : [ path ]
```

Our `search` function is cleaned up a bit too -

```
const search = async (query, path = ".") =>
  Parallel (files (path))
    .filter (x => basename (x) === query)
```

Finally, `readPackages` -

```
const readPackages = async (f, path = ".") =>
  Parallel (search ("package.json", path))
    .map (readFile)
    .then
      ( buffers =>
          buffers .map (b => f (JSON .parse (String (b))))
      )
```

Behavior of each function is identical to the original implementations. Only now we have even more generic functions which can be reused in other areas of our program.

In this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56214040/633183), we use the `Parallel` module to implement a `dirs` function which recursively lists all directories at a given path.