# How to Array.map chain off of async await?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, functional-programming, async-await

How can I run Array.map off of an await?

```
const CLASS_PATH = 'User/matt/Github/project';
const PACKAGE_JSON = 'package.json';

const walk = async path => {
  let dirs = [];
  for (const file of await readdir(path)) {
    if ((await stat(join(path, file))).isDirectory()) {
      dirs = [
        ...dirs,
        file,
      ];
    }
  }
  return dirs;
};


async function main() {
  const packagePaths = await walk(CLASS_PATH)
        .map(pkgName => join(CLASS_PATH, pkgName, PACKAGE_JSON));

}
main();
```

Comment: Why not just `dirs.push(file)` ?

Comment: I think you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225285/633183) relevant

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, can I ask what you expect `main` to do? Are you trying to find the path to all `package.json` files in a given directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parenthesis `()` can always be used to change operator predescendence:

```
 (await walk(CLASS_PATH)).map(/*...*/)
```

Comment: You sir are amazing

Comment: I'm surprised you did not know that, you actually used that *in your code* already.

Comment: Cuz I copy and pasta a walk function >_<

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Promise.
So in your case:

```
const packagePaths = await Promise.all(walk(CLASS_PATH).map(async (item): Promise<number> => {
    await join(CLASS_PATH, pkgName, PACKAGE_JSON);
}));
```

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when
>   all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects
>   with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.