# Name for a function that maps and returns a resolved array of promises?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, abstraction

Maybe this is a stupid ask but I recently found myself using this abstraction often:

```
async function giveMeAName(cbAsync, initValue) {
  return await Promise.all(
    initValue.map(cbAsync),
  );
}
```

**Question:** Is this a common task to anyone else? If so, does it have a name? If not, maybe it's only partly realize, so does it remind you of anything? Otherwise, I can just delete the question.

Currently I'm using this function for this set of instructions.  Code below will get all directories of a path and collect all directories that have a package.json within:

```
const directories = (await getDirNamesByPath(rootPath));
const paths = await giveMeAName(addExistAdaptor, directories.map(joinPathWithName(rootPath)));
return await giveMeAName(collectJson, paths.filter(hasPath));
```

Comment: Btw., strictly speaking, this isn't functional, because FP is based on laws, mostly math laws. From this perspective, `Promise` is a lawless datatype who's acting weird. You should look into monadic types like `Task`, which handle asynchronous computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56193922/633183) a couple days ago that I tried helping you with, but you never replied :(

I've answered similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225285/633183) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56214040/633183)) that have generalised this pattern -

```
const Parallel = p =>
  ( { map: async f =>
        Promise .all ((await p) .map (x => f (x)))
    , filter: async f =>
        Promise .all ((await p) .filter (x => f (x)))
    , flatMap: async f =>
        Promise .all ((await p) .map (x => f (x))) .then (ys => [] .concat (...ys))
    , // ...
    }
  )
```

You can see it being used in this way with `files`, which recursively lists all paths to all files in a directory and its subdirectories -

```
const { readdir, stat } =
  require ("fs") .promises

const { join } =
  require ("path")

const files = async (path = ".") =>
  (await stat (path)) .isDirectory ()
    ? Parallel (readdir (path))
        .flatMap (f => files (join (path, f)))
    : [ path ]
```

And a specialisation, `search`, which returns all paths matching a query -

```
const { basename } =
  require ("path")

const search = async (query, path = ".") =>
  Parallel (files (path))
    .filter (f => basename (f) === query)
```

And `readPackages` which recursively reads all `package.json` files at a specified path -

```
const { readFile } =
  require ("fs") .promises

const readPackages = async (path = ".") =>
  Parallel (search ("package.json", path))
    .map (readFile)
    .then
      ( buffers =>
          buffers .map (b => JSON .parse (String (b)))
      )
```

Finally, a slightly more complex example, `dirs`, which works like `files` but recursively lists directories only. The level of recursion can be controlled by the `depth` parameter -

```
const dirs = async (path = ".", depth = Infinity) =>
  (await stat (path)) .isDirectory ()
    ? depth === -1
        ? []
        : Parallel (readdir (path))
            .flatMap (f => dirs (join (path, f), depth - 1))
            .then (results => [ path, ...results ])
    : []
```

To see what these programs look like *without* the `Parallel` module, see the linked Q&A's above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242701/conforming-my-readpackagefiles-to-fit-inside-parallel-function

Answer (score 0):

I use different names for it, depending on my needs in the application. Sometimes I use functions like that for specific use cases and name it accordingly. But the most generic name that I use quite often, is simply `resolveAll()`.

But I don't think there is any (semi-)official naming for it. So name it the way it makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `mapAll` or `awaitAll`?

Bluebird has a similar function simply called [`map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) which does something quite similar (it returns the mapped promise rather than resolving it).