# How await a recursive Promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, async-await

I have written a recursive Promise in javascript which seems to be working fine but I wanted to test it using setTimeout() to be sure that I'm awaiting correctly before continuing with the execution. Here is the gist of my code:

```js
try{
  await renameFiles(); // <-- await here
  console.log("do other stuff");
}
catch(){
}

const renameFiles = (path) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Renaming files...");

    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(file) => {
      // if file is a directory ...
      let newPath = path.join(path, file);
      resolve( renameFiles(newPath) ); // <- recursion here!
      // else rename file ...
    }
    resolve();
  })
```

I've tested it with setTimeout() like this:

```js
const renameFiles = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    // all previous code goes here
    },2000)
  }
}
```

and the output is:

```
"Renaming files..."
"Renaming files..."
// bunch of renaming files...
"do other stuff"
"Renaming files..."
"Renaming files..."
```

So it looks like it's awaiting for a bit but then it continues the execution at some point.

I'm also doubting I'm testing it wrong. Any idea where the problem may be?

Comment: You are calling `resolve` many times, this makes no sense. Per [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise#Constructor) only the first resolution matters: `If the associated promise has already been resolved, either to a value, a rejection, or another promise, this method does nothing.`

Comment: Collect the promises into an array and await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)

Comment: I think @AlexanderAzarov found the issue. `renameFiles` gets resolved early and the async function continues while the recursion also continues. Possibly just removing that `resolve(renameFiles(newPath))` and putting just `renameFiels(newPath)` will fix it.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen I've already tried without ```resolve(renameFiles(newPath))``` but it didn't fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned - multiple resolve invocations don't make sense. However that is not the only problem in the code. Root invocation got resolved when its recursive call started for first sub directory. This code will process directories in hierarchical order

***rename.js***

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const inputPath = path.resolve(process.argv[2]);
const newName = 'bar.txt';

async function renameFiles(filePath) {
    for (const file of fs.readdirSync(filePath)) {
        const newPath = path.join(filePath, file);
        const descriptor = fs.lstatSync(newPath);
        if (descriptor.isDirectory()) {
            await renameFiles(newPath)
        } else if (descriptor.isFile()) {
            await renameFile(file);
        }
    }
}

async function renameFile(file) {
    console.log(`Renaming ${file} to ${newName}`)
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log(`Renamed ${file} to ${newName}`)
           resolve();
       }, 300)
    });
}

async function main() {
    console.log(`Renaming all files in ${inputPath} to ${newName}`);
    await renameFiles(inputPath);
    console.log('Finished');
}

main();
```

you can run it like

```
node rename.js relativeFolderName
```

or if order doesn't matter, then you can use `map` and `Promise.all` as mentioned by @Tiago Coelho

```
const renameFiles = async path => {
    const renamePromises = fs.readdirSync(path).map(file => {
      if (isDirectory(file)) {
          const newPath = path.join(path, file);
          return renameFiles(newPath)
      } else {
          return renamefile(file);
      }  
    });
    await Promise.all(renamePromises);
}
```

Comment: Good clean solution. Voted up.
On your second solution you need to return the promise, not await, and so it does not need to be async. Also you got some extra () after the map that wont really work

Comment: Right, there is an error in second solution, will fix, thank you. I wanted something like `(async () => console.log('Async!'))()` to get anonymous async/await execution

Comment: It still doesn't' work for me. With the solution given by @udalmik my code looks like this
```return new Promise(resolve=>{
 setTimeout(async()=>{
  // CODE HERE
},2000)
```
which end-up being never resolved.
Adding ```resolve()``` after the for loop also end up not awaiting properly.
  })

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your problem or what are you trying to solve with setTimeout. Updated answer with test run.

Comment: @udalmik I'm using setTimeout to delay the execution so I can test the "await". If I use setTimeout inside ```async function renameFile(file)``` the program will not await and will continue.

Comment: What an impressive effort was put in this answer. Kudos for your patience as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing one big complicated function, I'll suggest a more decomposed approach.

First we start with a `files` that recursively lists all files at a specified `path` -

```
const { readdir, stat } =
  require ("fs") .promises

const { join } =
  require ("path")

const files = async (path = ".") =>
  (await stat (path)) .isDirectory ()
    ? Promise
        .all
          ( (await readdir (path))
              .map (f => files (join (path, f)))
          )
        .then
          ( results =>
             [] .concat (...results)
          )
    : [ path ]
```

We have a way to list all files now, but we only wish to rename some of them. We'll write a generic `search` function to find all files that match a query -

```
const { basename } =
  require ("path")

const search = async (query, path = ".") =>
  (await files (path))
    .filter (x => basename (x) === query)
```

Now we can write your `renameFiles` function as a specialisation of `search` -

```
const { rename } =
  require ("fs") .promises

const { dirname } =
  require ("path")

const renameFiles = async (from = "", to = "", path = ".") =>
  Promise
    .all
      ( (await search (from, path))
          .map
            ( f =>
                rename
                  ( f
                  , join (dirname (f), to)
                  )
             )
       )
```

To use it, we simply call `renameFiles` with its expected parameters -

```
renameFiles ("foo", "bar", "path/to/someFolder")
  .then
    ( res => console .log ("%d files renamed", res.length)
    , console.error
    )

// 6 files renamed
```

---

Reviewing our programs above, we see some patterns emerging with our use of `Promise.all`, `await`, and `map`. Indeed these patterns can be extracted and our programs can be further simplified. Here's `files` and `renameFiles` revised to use a generic `Parallel` module -

```
const files = async (path = ".") =>
  (await stat (path)) .isDirectory ()
    ? Parallel (readdir (path))
        .flatMap (f => files (join (path, f)))
    : [ path ]

const renameFiles = (from = "", to = "", path = "") =>
  Parallel (search (from, path))
    .map
      ( f =>
          rename
            ( f
            , join (dirname (f), to)
            )
      )
```

The `Parallel` module was originally derived in [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225285/633183). For additional insight and explanation, please follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to wait for all the files in the directory to resolve. So you will need to do a `Promise.all` and use a `map` instead of a `forEach`

something like this:

```
try{
  await renameFiles(); // <-- await here
  console.log("do other stuff");
}
catch(){
}

const renameFiles = (path) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Renaming files...");

    const allFilesRenamePromises = fs.readdirSync(path).map(file => {
      if(file.isDirectory()) {
        let newPath = path.join(path, file);
        return renameFiles(newPath); // <- recursion here!
      } else {
        // rename file ...
      }
    }
    resolve(Promise.all(allFilesRenamePromises));
  })
```

Comment: You should use the original code with `await` from the question though, not the one with `.then()` from Pavithra's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56301557/633183) I showed you how to solve your problem using mainly functional techniques. In this answer, we'll see modern JavaScript features like async iterables make this kind of thing even easier -

```
const files = async function* (path = ".")
{ if ((await stat (path)) .isDirectory ())
    for (const f of await readdir (path))
      yield* files (join (path, f))
  else
     yield path
}

const search = async function* (query, path = ".")
{ for await (const f of files (path))
    if (query === basename (f))
      yield f
}

const renameFiles = async (from = "", to = "", path = ".") =>
{ for await (const f of search (from, path))
    await rename
      ( f
      , join (dirname (f), to)
      )
}

renameFiles ("foo", "bar", "path/to/someFolder")
  .then (_ => console .log ("done"), console.error)
```

Answer (score -1):

For completeness, I'll post the entire solution based on **@udalmik** suggestion. The only difference is that I'm wrapping `async function renameFile(file)` inside a **Promise**.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const inputPath = path.resolve(process.argv[2]);
const newName = 'bar.txt';

async function renameFiles(filePath) {
    for (const file of fs.readdirSync(filePath)) {
        const newPath = path.join(filePath, file);
        const descriptor = fs.lstatSync(newPath);
        if (descriptor.isDirectory()) {
            await renameFiles(newPath)
        } else if (descriptor.isFile()) {
            await renameFile(file);
        }
    }
}

async function renameFile(file) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(`Renaming ${file} to ${newName}`);
    resolve();
  })
}

async function main() {
    console.log(`Renaming all files in ${inputPath} to ${newName}`);
    await renameFiles(inputPath);
    console.log('Finished');
}

main();
```

The reason for using the Promise is that  I want to await for all the files to be renamed before continuing the execution (i.e. `console.log('Finished');`).

I've **tested** it using setTimeout

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(`Renaming ${file} to ${newName}`);
    },1000)
    resolve(); // edited missing part
  })
```

The solution took a different path from my original question but I guess it works for me.

Comment: Actually you didn't change anything with wrapping the result with fake `Promise` in `readFile`. Please check **Async Functions** section in [this tutorial](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: @udalmik thanks for the link. I think I understand how to use await, but maybe there is something that I miss when using setTimeout?Is there a better/different way to test it? If you don't wrap the function inside a Promise the output will not be "synchronous"  ( when using setTimeout() )

Comment: If you want to emulate some delay of renaming the file - then setTimeout is a way to go, you just missed call to resolve fn, I've added delay to my answer. I wanted to point that no sense to wrap result of async operation with promise (your first code snippet) with immediate resolve call, JS engine will do it for you.

Comment: @udalmik yes, I know there's no need to wrap the result inside a Promise. I did it because when using ```setTimeout``` it was necessary. That's the part that confuses me: why do I need to wrap setTimeout inside a Promise to make it work?

Answer (score -3):

try to change the await code like this. this might help you.

```
try{
  const renameFilesPromise = renameFiles();
  renameFilesPromise.then({      <-- then is a callback when promise is resolved
    console.log("do other stuff");
  })
}
catch(){
}

const renameFiles = (path) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Renaming files...");

    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(file) => {
      // if file is a directory ...
      let newPath = path.join(path, file);
      resolve( renameFiles(newPath) ); // <- recursion here!
      // else rename file ...
    }
    resolve();
  })
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet and it may work, but I'm trying to avoid the callback-hell. I have a bunch of await after that call.

Comment: Ok, you can use the await itself. Try increasing the setTimeOut. Cause setTimeOut automatically resolves in 2000ms.

Comment: this will not work either, because the moment you call the first resolve(renameFiles(newPath)) you essentially ignore the remaining files in the loop