# DELETE FILES with Node.js

Tags: node.js, file, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to delete some files and then show a message.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
File deleted

Folder Cleared!!!
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
Folder Cleared!!!

File deleted
```

**The current code is:**

```js
function clearConverted() {
      const resp = new Promise(async (resolve) => {

        const converted = glob.sync('./converted/*.mp4');


        if (converted.length) {
          const fs = require('fs');
          const promises = converted.map(v => {

            fs.unlink(v, () => console.log('File deleted'))
          })
          Promise.all(promises);
        } else {
          console.log('No files to delete');
        }
        resolve();
      })
      resp.then(console.log('Folder Cleared!!!'))
    }
```

May you help me?

Comment: All-caps in 2020? Seriously?

Comment: don't use `require` inside a loop

Comment: [What is the explicit Promise constructor anti-pattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) does not return a promise. You're probably looking for [fsPromises.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_unlink_path) ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per my original comments on your question, you have heaps to fix with your code -

- Don't use `require` inside a loop
- [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) does not return a Promise.You're probably looking for [fsPromises.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_unlink_path)
- [What is the explicit Promise constructor anti-pattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

```js
const { unlink } =
  require("fs").promises  // <-- fsPromises

function clearConverted() {
  const converted =
    glob.sync("./converted/*.mp4")

  if (converted.length === 0)
    return Promise.resolve([])

  const promises = 
    converted.map(v => unlink(v).then(_ => v))

  return Promise.all(promises)
}

clearConverted() // <-- returns a promise!
  .then(deletedFiles => console.log("done! deleted files:", deletedFiles))

// done! deleted files: ./converted/foo.mp4, ./converted/bar.mp4
```

And see how we removed `console.log` side effects from the function? This allows our function to collect meaningful data, like the file names, and return a list of deleted files. Because the `console.log` effect is now *outside* of `clearConverted` we can change it, if we wish.

For example, we could simply display the count of deleted files, in a less verbose program -

```js
clearConverted()
  .then(deletedFiles =>
    console.log("done! deleted %d files.", deletedFiles.length)
  )

// done! deleted 9 files.
```

And we can do more. An obvious improvement now is to make `clearConverted` a generic function which accepts the `path` as an argument -

```js
function unlinkFiles (path = "") { // <-- generic name and path parameter
  const files =
    glob.sync(path)

  if (files.length === 0)
    return Promise.resolve([])
  else
    return Promise.all(files.map(f => unlink(f).then(_ => f)))
}

unlinkFiles("./converted/*.mp4") // <-- supply path at call site
  .then(deletedFiles => console.log("done! deleted files:", deletedFiles))
  .catch(console.error) // <-- don't forget to catch Promises too
```

---

Modern features like `async` allow us to skip some of the ceremony around Promises -

```js
async function unlinkFiles (path = "") { // <-- async keyword
  const files =
    glob.sync(path)

  return files.length === 0
     ? []  // <-- automatically wrapped in a Promise
     : Promise.all(files.map(f => unlink(f).then(_ => f)))
}
```

Now if you wanted, you could make the function accept a `glob` result instead of a `path` -

```js
const unlinkFiles = async (files = []) => // <-- arrow function
  files.length === 0
    ? []
    : Promise.all(files.map(f => unlink(f).then(_ => f)))

unlinkFiles(glob.sync("./converted/*.mp4")) // <-- use glob as input
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

When you detangle the wires, programming can be fun *and* easy. Sadly, languages like JavaScript also make it easy to shoot yourself in the foot, so there's a lot of misery before enlightenment.

---

I have other answers involving the `fs` module and Promises. These additional code examples may help provide additional insight -

- [Recursively rename files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56305541/633183)
- [Recursively read all package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225285/633183)
- [Recursively list all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56214040/633183)

Answer (score 0):

When you call Promise.all add .then method there, something likethis:

```
Promise.all(promises).then((response) => console.log("Folder Cleared")).catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

And also when you require modules or dependencies, you declare them at the top of the file and not inside functions or loops.

Comment: I have used it but still not working, it has to show File Delete before Folder Cleared